# UK Tier 2 visa validity after I quit my job

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I was a UK Tier 2 visa holder from China. I resigned from my position in the UK and got a job in Germany. If I travel outside of the UK, could I still use my Tier 2 visa to enter the country within 60 days?

Comment: When was your visa due to expire?

Comment: My visa still has two more years to go. But I quit my job, so the company will notify the Home office to stop sponsor my visa. Then it will starts a 60-day curtail period